# CalledProcessError getting past try block with eventlet

Tags: python, exception, eventlet

I am using eventlet for green threads (in particular, the wsgi server). To easily add this functionality to the existing codebase, I used eventlet's monkey_patch functionality.

The very top of my file is therefore this:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
```

I now have a function a little farther down:

```
def ping(host: str) -> bool:
    try:
        ret = subprocess.check_output(["ping", "-c", "4", host], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL).decode("utf-8")
        for line in ret.splitlines()[1:-3]:
            if host in line:
                return True
        return False
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return False
```

If the target is not reachable, the behaviour of this function baffles me a little. If the monkey_patch is not enabled, then this returns `False`, as I would expect. If, however, they monkey_patch is in place, it raises a `CalledProcessError`.

I do not understand how this is possible - it should be immediately caught. What is going on here?

Edit 1:
Here's an example interpreter session:

```
>>> ping("192.168.0.233")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 8, in ping
    ret = subprocess.check_output(["ping", "-c", "4", host], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL).decode("utf-8")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 418, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ping', '-c', '4', '192.168.0.233']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Edit 2:
As it turns out, if I catch the exception with `except Exception` or even a bare `except`, the exception gets caught fine. I suppose I will use this until a more proper solution can be found. I am still dumbfounded by this behaviour, however.

Comment: Your code erases error information that could be used to debug problem. Show exception. In production code log everything abnormal.

Comment: I don't quite follow. Where am I erasing error information? Do you mean because I am catching the exception? But that's the part that doesn't work - I want the exception to be caught. I have nonetheless added an example interpreter session illustrating the problem. (By the way, the provided code is almost a working example - you just need to import subprocess)

Comment: Where erasing - `return False` clears `sys.exc_info`. I just understood the problem, see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is two distinct exception class objects with same name in stdlib and green-patched modules. In code they look identical, but for `try/except` they're different types.

Sorry, no stable solution right now. Patches are welcome!

Workaround: call `eventlet.monkey_patch()` before any other code execution.

Subscribe for news on this issue here: https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/413

Root cause is that monkey patching creates a new module, "copies" known names into it while replacing links to green modules and places that module under stdlib name into `sys.modules`. (As opposed to modifying stdlib module in-place which is not possible because Python C-API restrictions)

Comment: The very first two lines of my file are `import eventlet` and `eventlet.monkey_path()`. How could I possibly do the monkey_patch any earlier?

Comment: Does this file execute first or maybe some framework loads it? Could you post a minimal reproduction script somewhere or send to me?

Comment: I mean... it's not minimal, but the code I included works on its own and does reproduce the issue. I can make an actual minimal example tomorrow if you wish